# How to add to an array in Postmates and then export?

Tags: javascript, arrays, postman

Lets say I have an array as an environment variable on Postman:

```
tags: ["11111111", "22222222", "33333333", "44444444"]
```

I then have this JSON body response from Postman:

```
{
"id": "12345678",
"tagging": {
   "tags": [
       {
         "id": "11111111"}]
}
```

I want to compare the array "tags" data to the JSON body and record the "id" into the array.

How do I change the array so that it now looks something like:

```
tags: ["11111111":["12345678"], "22222222", "33333333", "44444444"]
```

I would do this over and over again say, 10000 times and then would want to count how many "ids" are in each tag.

I'm an amateur coder so please bear with me as I learn the lingo.

Answer (score 0):

Before we can start coding, we'll need to sort out the desired data format. Your example contains a syntax error:

```
tags: ["11111111":["12345678"], "22222222", "33333333", "44444444"]
```

Should probably be:

```
{ tags: [ { "11111111": ["12345678"] }, "22222222", "33333333", "44444444"] }
```

With the syntax error fixed, there's still more we might want to change. Even though javascript won't complain, `tags` is now an `array` of mixed types: it contains an object (`{ "11..": ["123..."] }`) and strings (`"222..", "333.."`). I'd say you want to change it to this:

```
{ 
  tags: {
    "11111111": [ "12345678" ],
    "22222222": [ ],
    "33333333": [ ]
  }
}
```

We've made `tags` into an object that stores an array of ids for every tag. When there are no ids, the array is empty.

To initialize this object, we loop over the array of tags:

```js
const tags = ["11111111", "22222222", "33333333", "44444444"];

const tagGroups = {};
tags.forEach(t => { tagGroups[t] = []; });

console.log(tagGroups);
```

Now that you have your empty groups set up, you're ready to go over the data.

```js
const tags = ["11111111", "22222222", "33333333", "44444444"];
const data = [{
  "id": "12345678",
  "tagging": {
    "tags": [{
      "id": "11111111"
    }]
  }
}];

const tagGroups = {};
tags.forEach(t => {
  tagGroups[t] = [];
});

data.forEach(d => {
  d.tagging.tags.forEach(tag => {
    tagGroups[tag.id].push(d.id);
  });
});

console.log(tagGroups);
```

You can now check how much a tag occurs by calling `tagGroups[id].length`. E.g.:

```
console.log(tagGroups["11111111"].length); // Logs `1`
```

There are shorter/other ways to write this code, but I tried to keep it as readable as possible.

Note: if your `data` contains a tag that's not in your `tags` array, the code will break.

Comment: Thank you so much! setting up the arrays worked perfectly. I am getting a "data.forEach is not a function" error as the JSON body is an object, not an array. Please advise.

Comment: If it's only one object, you can skip the outer `foreach` and replace `d` by `data`. You can also wrap `data` in an array if you want to keep your code compatible with lists of data. I.e..: `[data].forEach`

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks! You’ve made my first experience on this site very delightful.